# Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Как пишется "в()разрез" в придложении, вроде "Идти в()разрез с существующими правилами"?

Answer (score 1):

Наречие ***ВСЕГДА*** (!) пишется СЛИТНО... В данном случае 'в()разрез' отвечает на вопрос КАК? И - этим всё сказано, - слитно...

Answer (score 0):

Слитно: *вразрез*.

Comment: Но "в шутку" ведь пишется раздельно. И "разрез" - вполне литературное слово.

Comment: Вполне, вполне. :) И тем не менее Завада права. Правописание наречий надёжнее проверять в словарном порядке.

Answer (score 0):

В данном конкретном примере вразрез-наречие,поэтому пишется слитно

Answer (score 0):

В данном прЕдложении "вразрез" пишется слитно.